# How should I configure anycast IP with GCE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Suppose, I am running an application in 3 different regions (us, europe and asia) on Google Cloud. I would like to configure an anycast ip so that my users can connect to their nearest server. I am not running a CDN here. Is this possible and what are the steps for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use global HTTP/S Load Balancer, it provides a single anycast address and load balances to the closest server - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/cross-region-example